# Axis of Symmetry Coords Causes $A + B = -A$

Tags: conic-sections

I noticed something interesting while doing some homework on finding the vertex of a graph, and was wondering if anyone had an explanation for it.

Solving for $f(X) = A(X ^ 2) + BX$, I saw that for any numbers $A$ and $B$, plugging $X$ as the axis of symmetry would cause $A + B$ to equal $-A$

Random example:
$f(X) = 7(X ^ 2) + 273X$

Plugging in the axis of symetry gives me 
$f(-19.5) = 7(-19.5 ^ 2) + 273(-19.5) = 2661.75 - 5323.5 = -2661.75$

I thought this seemed interesting :D

Comment: you mean $f(-\frac{b}{2a}) = a\frac {b^2}{4a^2} - b\frac {b}{2a} = -\frac {b^2}{4a^2}$?

Comment: I think, instead of $A + B = -A$, their example shows that they discovered that if $T$ is the $x$-coordinate of the axis of symmetry for a quadratic  defined by $f(X) = AX^2 + BX$, we have that $f(T) = AT^2 + BT = -AT^2$ (it actually is a challenge to find nice-looking notation here)